# How to produce multiplication tables/diagram/list using a script

Tags: tables, lists, diagrams

I am a math teacher and would like to produce a LaTeX document that generates multiplication tables. I would like the output to be like

1x5=5

2x5=10

etc.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 10):

I can think of two solutions:

1. using `pgf`'s `\foreach` and `\pgfmathparse`
2. using LaTeX `\@for` and counters for arithmetic

## Solution using `pgf`

With a reasonably recent version of `pgf` you can write:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\begin{document}

    \foreach \b in {1,...,5}{%
        \noindent%
        \foreach \a in {1,2,...,10}{%
            \pgfmathparse{int(\a*\b)}%
             $\a \times \b = {\pgfmathresult}$ \\
        }
        \newpage
    }    

\end{document}
```

which is easily adapted to different styles or functions and highly readable.
The two `foreach` loop through the list in curly brackets, the inner one is the one actually generating the table, the outer is generating the five tables.

The `\pgfmathparse` macro stores in `\pgfmathresult` the result of evaluating the expression `{int(\a*\b)}`.
Right after the evaluation of `\pgfmathparse` the macros `\a`, `\b` and `\pgfmathresult` are setup to hold the first operand, the second and the result of the multiplication respectively.

To make the implementation reusable you can package it into a new macro:

```
\newcommand{\MultTableOf}[1]{
    \foreach \a in {1,2,...,10}{%
        \pgfmathparse{int(\a*\b)}%
        $\a \times \b = {\pgfmathresult}$ \\
    }
}
```

and then calling it with `\MultTableOf{3}` for instance.

## Solution using plain LaTeX

If you feel that using `pgf` is an overkill (it has an incredible lot of more advanced features) or it is not installed in your system, you may consider a pure TeX solution as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\def\MultTables{1,2,3,4,5}
\def\MultFactors{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
\newcount\r
\@for\a:=\MultTables\do{
    \@for\b:=\MultFactors\do{
        \r=\a
        \multiply\r by \b
        $\a \times \b = \number\r $ \\
    }
}
\makeatother
```

which is a bit less flexible and less readable but requires no extra package.
There are two ingredients here: the use of `\@for` for looping (a more primitive version of pgf's `foreach`) and the use of counters to perform simple aritmetic.

Answer (score 5):

The virtue of this solution is that it right-justifies numbers to produce a nice alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{index}
\newcounter{product}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcount\maxtotal
\newcommand\multt[2]{%
  \maxtotal=#1%
  \multiply\maxtotal by #2%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \setcounter{product}{0}%
  \whiledo{\theindex<#2}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \addtocounter{product}{#1}%
    \noindent\( \makebox[\widthof{#2}][r]{\theindex}\times #1 =%
      \makebox[\widthof{\the\maxtotal}][r]{\theproduct} \)\\
  }%
}
\parskip 1EM
\begin{document}
\multt{5}{13}\par
\multt{9}{12}
\end{document}
```

[image]